# Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) redirects to Roaming folder

Tags: c#, iis

I have a service that needs to retrieve some stuff from the local app folder but when I do Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) it returns the Roaming folder instead of the Local one...

My Application pool is using a system account and I made sure that on the ISS server, the **loadUserProfile** and **setProfileEnvironment** are both set to true for that particular application pool...

What am I missing here? why it is not returning the local folder instead of the Roaming one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`. Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx - it clearly says about `ApplicationData`:

> ApplicationData - The directory that serves as a common repository for
>   application-specific data for the current roaming user

Comment: ouch! you were right! I didn't notice of that one! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData
```

Will give you the local app data folder.